# How do I access a SQLITE database from HTML and the output thus obtained be a drop down list?

Tags: php, html, sqlite

```
<select>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

The values A, B, C must be obtained from a SQLITE database. How can I do that?

Comment: Find a php library that interacts with sqlite. You cannot access sqlite from HTML, you access from php, and then output data to templates.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, HTML alone cannot access sqlite databases. But, there are many tools, which get you closer to what you like. I recommand you to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_framework to learn about frameworks and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_frameworks for a list of existing frameworks (it is outdated, but still very long)

Many frameworks offer a functionality called "Templates". This is a mechanism, which allows you to embed processing instructions (e.g. getting values from a database) into your HTML File. Examples are ctemplate, mustache and many more. Those tools process your HTML and insert the values from a database into the right place in your template at the web server and send the client the complete HTML.

There are also ways to manipulate the contents of your page at the client site by javascript. Angular.js and react are only two big names that I am aware of. But also these would require a web server, which can access a database and deliver the values.